# Twitter API Strange Encoded Chars Returned

Tags: api, twitter, character-encoding

I'm building a little app that uses the twitter search api: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=funny

Now everything is working great, but sometimes it messes up my PHP script when the tweets contain chineze chars. Now on my site I use UTF-8 meta headers. Can someone tell me how to convert the following chars which were outputted by the Twitter API to a readable format?

EXAMPLE OUTPUT:

> \u525B\u624D\u5728igfw.tk\u770B\u5230\u6709\u4E00\u500B\u535A\u5BA2\u63D0\u4F9B\u6BCF\u534A\u5C0F\u6642\u6539\u5BC6\u78BC\u7684ssh,\u62FF\u4F86\u7DF4\u7FD2\u4E00\u4E0Bbash\u8173\u672C\uFF0C\u65B7\u958B\u5F8C\u6703\u81EA\u52D5\u91CD\u65B0\u9023\u63A5\uFF0C\u4F7F\u7528Ctrl-C\u9000\u51FA,Cygwin\u4E0A\u7DE8\u5BEB\uFF0CLinux\u8A72\u6C92\u554F\u984C\uFF0CMAC\u81EA\u884C\u6E2C\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the \uXXXX are unicode codes for the characters

you could use a table of values pairing with the utf. or pack the string as json and use json_decode that already has that behavior.

you can see an example of how to do the conversion in the Service_json.json_decode() source, as one implementation that comes to my mind now

http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON/redirected